# Using JPA Listener to set Current User

Tags: spring, jpa

I'm currently having a problem using a JPA Listener to update/persist the current user updating/creating an object. Here is the JPAListener's code

```
private static UserSession userSession = null;//Scoped-session bean
// yes i know i'm accessing a session stored in HTTP in persistence layer

@PreUpdate
public void preUpdate(AbstractDAOAuditedEntity abstractEntity) {
    abstractEntity.setModificationDate(new Date());
    // use userSession here to set currentUser or system
}

@PrePersist
public void prePersist(AbstractDAOAuditedEntity abstractEntity) {
    // same
}

public static void setUserSession(UserSession userSession) {
    DAOEntityListener.userSession = userSession;
}
```

If i do it while processing an HttpRequest it works, because userSession is bound to an Http Session managed by spring.

But now i have a new usage, i'm receiving data from a JmsMessage, this mean i'm running in a thread without HttpContext, and so the listener crash when trying to use userSession.

As a really quick and really dirty fix i did the following :

```
boolean haveUser = true;
try {
    userSession.getUser();
} catch (Exception e) {
    haveUser = false;
}
if (!haveUser) {}
```

My question is not so about how to make it works but how i should have handle this properly, whether i'm in HttpContext or not ?

Comment: I think you should not access the HTTP session from your persistence layer. You should have some intermediate mechanism to provide user info (a static helper, a bean or a service layer). At the beginning of the session you can then supply user info from frontend to the intermediate layer.

Comment: @zero_cool I know that i need some intermediary level, but i'm asking for somewhat a proper solution, not just a more elegant workaround.

Comment: Use Spring security or implement something like the the Spring SecurityContextHolder See 9.4.4 : http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#tech-intro-sec-context-persistence

Comment: @AlanHay so that means that i should not use my session bean here but instead store my currentUser as the principal right ? And if i'm out of HTTP Context, i use `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication()`. At start i wanted to be able to inject a session bean without hardly depends on Spring (just let him handle things behind the scene), but guess i'll have no choice.